# Copy & Delete Sheet Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I've got assistance from user name @Ike to copy and delete cell. When I click the button based on images, few new sheet will be created named (based on cell value it indicate into the cell) - Example: A1, A2,B1,... and it will copy sheet 6.1.

[image]

The code that has been share work really well. The code is shown below:

This one adds a sheet if there is a value in the phases range and it does not yet exist - by using existsSheet-function

```
Public Sub addSheetsIfNotExists(wsSourceToCopy As Worksheet, arrValidPhases As Variant)

Dim newSheetName As String

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(arrValidPhases, 1)
    newSheetName = arrValidPhases(i, 1)
    If newSheetName <> "" Then
        If existsSheet(newSheetName) = False Then
            With ThisWorkbook
                wsSourceToCopy.Copy after:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = newSheetName
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub

Private Function existsSheet(SheetNameToCheck As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetNameToCheck)
If Not ws Is Nothing Then existsSheet = True
End Function
```

This one removes a sheet if it isn't present in the phases-range:

```
Public Sub checkSheetsForPhase(wsStartToCheck As Worksheet, arrValidPhases As Variant)
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, fExists As Boolean
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Index > wsStartToCheck.Index Then
        fExists = False
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrValidPhases, 1)
            If ws.Name = arrValidPhases(i, 1) Then
                fExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If fExists = False Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I can call these subs from click event like this:

```
Public Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("6.1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("6")

Dim arrPhases As Variant

With sh2
    arrPhases = .Range("C8:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

addSheetsIfNotExists sh1, arrPhases
checkSheetsForPhase sh1, arrPhases

sh2.Activate
End Sub
```

My problem that I faces right now is, when I have new sheet, let say Sheet 8, and the sheet is located AFTER Sheet 6.1. When I click the button "Copy & Delete Sheet", the code above will work, but it will delete my new created Sheet name "Sheet 8". I expect, when I click the button "copy & delete sheet", the sheet sequence will be like this:

Original: 1,2,3,4,5,6,6.1,8

After click: 1,2,3,4,5,6,6.1,A1,A2,B1,C1,D1,D2,E1,8

Need some help on this. TQ

Comment: Remove the phase bit and just check all sheets?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `sht1 and sht2` are hard-coded in the click event, and when `checkSheetsForPhase` is called, `Sheet8` is deleted.

The corrected approach is as follows:

- Assume that `Sheet8` has the same data layout as `Sheet6`, and ensure that `Sheet8.x` exists in the workbook and it is at the right of `Sheet8`
- Update the object references for `sht1` and `sht2` appropriately.

```vb
Public Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = ActiveSheet.Next
    Set sh2 = ActiveSheet
    Dim arrPhases As Variant
    With sh2
        arrPhases = .Range("C8:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row).Value
    End With
    addSheetsIfNotExists sh1, arrPhases
    checkSheetsForPhase sh1, arrPhases
    sh2.Activate
End Sub
```

---

Update: changed code is marked with **

```
Public Sub addSheetsIfNotExists(wsSourceToCopy As Worksheet, arrValidPhases As Variant)
    Dim newSheetName As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = UBound(arrValidPhases, 1) To 1 Step -1 ' ***
        newSheetName = arrValidPhases(i, 1)
        If newSheetName <> "" Then
            If existsSheet(newSheetName) = False Then
                With ThisWorkbook
                    wsSourceToCopy.Copy after:=.Worksheets(wsSourceToCopy.Index) ' **
                    ActiveSheet.Name = newSheetName
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub checkSheetsForPhase(wsStartToCheck As Worksheet, arrValidPhases As Variant)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, fExists As Boolean
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Index > wsStartToCheck.Index And Val(ws.Name) = 0 Then ' **
            fExists = False
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrValidPhases, 1)
                If ws.Name = arrValidPhases(i, 1) Then
                    fExists = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If fExists = False Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @taller_ExcelHome , meaning I need to create one additional Sheet call "8.x"? Still not working.

Comment: Please share a screenshot which has Sheet 8. Do both button on Sheet6 and Sheet8 have shared click_event code? What's scenario to insert Sheet6.1 or Sheet8.1?

Comment: Sheet 8 is totally different type of Sheet. Then I plan to add more sheet after that (example: sheet 9, 10, 11, ...)

Comment: I have updated the code base on your revised OP.